# Program along with all the switches, runs great, but argparse '--help' throws a lot of errors

Tags: python, debugging, argparse

I am using argparse in Python to handle arguments in my program. For instance, as seen below, if I use the argument '-p' a specific module is execute. Now, all arguments and the program runs great. But when I try to get the '--help' for my program it crashes horribly (image).

Here is the code pertaining to argparse:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="something1.")
parser.add_argument('-x', '--xoo', help='something2', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-a', '--al', help='something3', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--conv', help='something4', type=float)
parser.add_argument('-p', '--pay', help='something5', type=float)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Any ideas as to how I can correct this error??

```
$ ./xoom.py -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./xoom.py", line 46, in <module>
    args = parser.parse_args()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1688, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1723, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1929, in _parse_known_args
    start_index = consume_optional(start_index)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1869, in consume_optional
    take_action(action, args, option_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1797, in take_action
    action(self, namespace, argument_values, option_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 994, in __call__
    parser.print_help()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 2319, in print_help
    self._print_message(self.format_help(), file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 2293, in format_help
    return formatter.format_help()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 279, in format_help
    help = self._root_section.format_help()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 209, in format_help
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 209, in format_help
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 515, in _format_action
    help_text = self._expand_help(action)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 601, in _expand_help
    return self._get_help_string(action) % params
TypeError: float argument required, not dict
```

Comment: I can't replicate. Adding `import argparse` to the top of that code and running it with the `-h` flag, I get an ordinary help menu rather than your error.

Comment: Please post the **text** of your error for searchability. Images are not indexed.

Comment: @Kevin I have added a function definition that involves a type conversion from string to float. That may have something to do with the error. Please see.

Comment: @MattDMo Didn't add the text of the error message to avoid a mess. Anyway, added it now.

Comment: @intellikid Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code to allow others to replicate the error.

Comment: I don't think `_calc` has any effect on the problem, because the exception is occurring on the line `args = parser.parse_args()`, which I'm guessing is executed before `_calc` is.

Comment: I recommend using a debugger and stepping through your code; as it is, there's not enough information to see what the problem is.

Comment: @Kevin I have added a more complete version of the code, could you locate the cause of the error?

Comment: Sorry @intellikid, even with this larger code sample, I get the same output as before. Everything looks like it should work fine.

Comment: There must be other code than the above fragment you provide, and that piece of code causes your crash. Have you tried running just the minimal code you've posted, without any other code around it?

Comment: @intellikid To debug, I recommend `pdb`. Add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` before the first `parser` statement. `pdb` docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you have % characters in your `something4` and/or `something5`.

Remove them and see if you still get the error.

If you really need % characters in those help texts, try replacing them with %% - i.e. use two percent characters in a row.

Update: Here is a minimal example which demonstrates why you are getting the error:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="something1.")
parser.add_argument('-c', '--conv', help='somet%fhing4', type=float)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Run with `--help` to generate the error message. Note the % character in the help string.

Comment: Do you mean the percent characters in the `elif args.conv` and `eliv args.pay` blocks? But those characters will get replaced by `amount` on their respective `print` lines. If you remove those percents, you'll get `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`.

Comment: I mean the OP's strings `something4` and `something5` in reality have %-characters in them, and those are causing the problem.

Comment: The problem is that in the description of one of these argparse agruments, I wrote "...after removing P's 5% fees'..   The error was because of that % symbol. I removed it and the error is gone. Thanks for all your help!!!

Comment: @user5402 Ha! Yes, I did. It's great that you knew the problem even when I modified the description while posting my code online. Kudos!